How can I retrieve UUID from firebase?
as the title, what syntax/method should I use to retrieve UUID from Firebase? I am developing a mobile app that involves accounts.
This is the syntax that I used to assign a random UUID for an account and push to Firebase.
lgID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

I tried to use
private FirebaseAuth auth;
String id = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid()

but it didn't work. This only works if the account has UID format. I believe UUID requires another method to retrieve. Or do I have to do a refactor and change everything back to UID.
Thank you.

"it didn't work" is really hard to help with. Please edit your question to include the minimal code that allows anyone to reproduce where you got stuck (read the link please, it's quite useful).

@FrankvanPuffelen Hello sir, I just edited the question as requested. Can you have a look at my question, please?

It's still not clear to me what you mean, and what the problem is. Can you show in the code in your question something that doesn't work the way you expect it to? E.g. console.log(id) and then show us the output - and what you expected to get instead.
